# How do I get event name of Observable created with .fromEvent

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I'm trying to restrict what events coming from common message bus should be emitted to server.
Allowed events are on `outgoingEvents` array. Problem is that to properly send them th server I need event name.

```
var Events = new EventEmitter();
var outgoingEvents = [
    'messageSubmit'
];

var outgoingMessages = Observable.fromArray(outgoingEvents)
.flatMap(function(eventName) {
    return Observable.fromEvent(Events, eventName);
}).subscribe(function() {
    // need event name here to properly encode message:

    // var eventName = ... should be 'messageSubmit'
    // var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // var encoded = JSON.stringify({ name: eventName, args: args });
    // socket.send(encoded);
});

Events.emit('messageSubmit', { message: 'Submitted!' }, {flags: 'ABC'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to reshape objects that get emmited to inservable in function that comes third parameter in `.fromEvent`

```
return Observable.fromEvent(Events, eventName, function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments[0]);
    return { name: eventName, args: args };
});
```

So it will be arguments of `.subscribe`:

```
var eventName = event.name;
var args = event.args;
```